# how to add trigger to updatepanel from usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, triggers, ascx

We have an updatepanel in our Default.aspx which we load our ASCx user controls. We need to add triggers dynamically for the updatepanel from our usercontrols.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do?  What are your "triggers" meant to do?  When you say dynamically do you mean in script at the web browser or in C# code dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve this is to put your trigger-button (link and etc..) where u want (for example in the user control u mentioned) and configure it as a trigger inside the updatepanel.

```
...//An example for a button you can put in a UserControl
<asp:Button ID="btnSomeButton" runat="server" Text="Refresh Panel" />
...
//An UpdatePanel located in your page - e.g. Default.aspx
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSomeButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
...
```